# I have a req to show different date time values based on different condition. One to display time in ISO, then in full date along with time & zone

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, formatting, time

I want to display time in 3 different formats, along side follow the translation strategy as well. That is if user selects to translate the page, user should be able to see the date in his/her local translated with selected time format method.

1. To display date in ISO format => `2010-01-19T14:32:35+03:00`
2. To display Date along with Time zone => `January 31, 2010, 14:32 (UTC+3:30)`
3. To display date in respect to when the record is created like => `5 hours ago, 2 minutes ago`

So I have this method in my JS file of LWC to update these date time format.

```
dateFormat(){
    if(this.myTaskWrappers) {
        this.myTaskWrappers = this.myTaskWrappers.map(item => {
            if(item.Due_Date__c){
                // console.log('DATE FORMAT')
                let dateobj = new Date(item.Due_Date__c); 

                if(this.updatedTimeFormat === 'ISO'){
                    this.isoDate = dateobj.toISOString();
                    item.Due_Date__c = this.isoDate;
                    console.log('this.isoDate '+this.isoDate); // 2023-06-29T18:30:00.000Z
                    let isoDateConvert= new Date(this.isoDate);
                    console.log('isoDateConvert '+isoDateConvert);

                }
                else if(this.updatedTimeFormat === 'Absolute'){
                    this.absoluteDate= dateobj.toString();
                    console.log('this.absoluteDate '+this.absoluteDate); // Fri Jun 30 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
                    item.Due_Date__c = this.absoluteDate;
                }
                else{
                    let dueDateInstance = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(LOCALE,
                        {   year: 'numeric',
                            month: 'long',
                            day: 'numeric'
                        }).format(dateobj);
                    item.Due_Date__c = dueDateInstance;
                }

            }
            return item;
            });
            
    }
}
```

1. ISO formatting is correct, my doubt is for +3:00 is always showing .000z
2. For 2nd time format i.e. 'Absolute', converted time is coming up with DAY and month I want to have in full format. How to achieve the same format which mentioned in above 2nd point.
3. For 3rd formatting, logic is not sorted yet in my mind. Any suggestions are welcome.

Please let me know if any other reference of code is needed.

Comment: Questions cannot be "hidden" on this site. There is no such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timezone returned by [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) is always UTC. I would keep it.

For the *Absolute* time you could leverage `Intl.DateTimeFormat` with an appropriate option object, e.g.:

```js
const dueDate = new Date(2010, 0, 31, 14, 32);
const hour12 = true; // Turn this to false if you want to have 24-hour time
const absoluteOptions = { 
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    hour12,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
};
const absoluteTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', absoluteOptions); // en-US to have month first
console.log(absoluteTimeFormat.format(dueDate)); // January 31, 2010 at 14:32 GMT+1
// to remove "at" you could leverage replace()
console.log(absoluteTimeFormat.format(dueDate).replace(' at ', ' ')); // January 31, 2010 2:32 PM GMT+1
```

The option object has a `hour12` property to let you switch between 12-hour (if true) and 24-hour (if false) time format, so it's true you would get `2:32 PM`, while if it's false you would get `14:32`.
I used [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove `at` from that string, but I advice against heavy string manipulation.

To display the difference between CreatedDate and Due_Date__c, once you have both Date object, you can create a third one for the difference, then extract its milliseconds calling [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and using them to calculate hours and minutes:

```js
const dueDate = new Date(2010, 0, 31, 14, 32);
const createdDate = new Date(2010, 0, 31, 13, 30);
const diffDate = new Date(dueDate.getTime() - createdDate.getTime());
let seconds = diffDate.getTime() / 1000;

const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600); // calling Math.floor to get an integer value

seconds -= hours * 3600;

const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

let diffString = `${minutes} minutes ago`;
if (hours > 0) {
  diffString = `${hours} hours ago, ${diffString}`;
}
console.log(diffString);
```

The `dateFormat` method should look like:

```js
dateFormat() {
    if (this.myTaskWrappers) {
        this.myTaskWrappers = this.myTaskWrappers.map((item) => {
            if (item.Due_Date__c) {
                const dueDate = new Date(item.Due_Date__c); 

                if (this.updatedTimeFormat === 'ISO') {
                    this.isoDate = dueDate.toISOString();
                    item.Due_Date__c = this.isoDate;
                    console.log('this.isoDate '+this.isoDate); // 2023-06-29T18:30:00.000Z
                }
                else if (this.updatedTimeFormat === 'Absolute') {
                    // Since Due_Date__c is just a Date, not a Datetime, we don't need hours, minutes and seconds
                    const absoluteOptions = { 
                        year: 'numeric',
                        month: 'long',
                        day: 'numeric'
                    };
                    const absoluteTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', absoluteOptions); // en-US to have month first
                    this.absoluteDate = absoluteTimeFormat.format(dueDate);
                    console.log('this.absoluteDate', this.absoluteDate);
                    item.Due_Date__c = this.absoluteDate;
                }
                else {
                    const createdDate = new Date(item.CreatedDate); // Assuming that CreatedDate has been retrieved
                    const diffDate = new Date(dueDate.getTime() - createdDate.getTime());
                    let seconds = diffDate.getTime() / 1000;

                    const secondsInAnHour = 3600;
                    const secondsInADay = secondsInAnHour * 24;
                    const secondsInAMonth = secondsInADay * 30;
                    const secondsInAYear = secondsInADay * 365;
                    
                    const years = Math.floor(seconds / secondsInAYear); 
                    seconds -= years * secondsInAYear;
                    
                    const months = Math.floor(seconds / secondsInAMonth);
                    seconds -= months * secondsInAMonth;
                    
                    const days = Math.floor(seconds / secondsInADay);
                    seconds -= days * secondsInADay;

                    const hours = Math.floor(seconds / secondsInAnHour); 
                    seconds -= hours * secondsInAnHour;

                    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

                    let diffString = `${minutes} minutes ago`;
                    if (hours > 0) {
                      diffString = `${hours} hours ago, ${diffString}`;
                    }
                    if (days > 0) {
                      diffString = `${days} days ago, ${diffString}`;
                    }
                    if (months > 0) {
                      diffString = `${months} months ago, ${diffString}`;
                    }
                    if (years > 0) {
                      diffString = `${years} years ago, ${diffString}`;
                    }
                    console.log('CreatedDate - DueDate:', diffString);
                    item.Due_Date__c = diffString;
                }

            }
            return item;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this help. I am doing ABSOLUTE one first, so what I could notice, it is always showing me time as 24:00 hrs... as for 12:00 AM. What could be the reason and how to update it. Plus I want to remove the 'at' from 'January 31, 2010 at 14:32 GMT+1' and add 'GMT+1' in brackets. Can I do it using string methods and modify it.

Comment: The more you mess with strings the harder it is for you to support multi-language orgs. You may not need to now, but it is possible you might in the end. In javascript, use a library that supports localisation, like luxon.

Comment: @SFLearner to switch between 24 or 12-hours time format you could set `hour12` property, I edited the answer to show it and to remove `at` from that string, but as Phil said, usually isn't wise messing too much with strings. Anyway [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) methods may meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW and RubenDG. I understand. 
However, even if I am setting hour12 property to true or false it is showing me time as 12:00 AM and 24:00 only respectively. Not the real time.

Comment: @SFLearner sorry, but I didn't get it, could you please elaborate or provide an example? If you run the code I posted in the browser's console, you'll see `14:32` if hour12 is false and  `2:32 PM` if true.

Comment: Sure @RubenDG, so if I am giving hour12 as false, it should show time as 12:07 as of now. However, it is showing 24:00 all the time irrespective of what time it is. I have placed my this component on Community page. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: @SFLearner Giving hour12 as false, it will not show "AM" or "PM" since it will use 24-hour time format, i.e. it should show `00:00` (if false) or `12:00 AM` (if true). Which locale are you using?  What's the type of `Due_Date__c`, Date or Datetime? Do you see 24:00 as output of `console.log('this.absoluteDate', this.absoluteDate);` or in the html?

Comment: @RubenDG , this is the output ---  
July 16, 2023 at 24:00 GMT+5:30 
and Due_Date__c is Date field. So I guess, as it is Date field that's why it might be showing 24:00 all the time. Am I right?

Comment: @SFLearner You're right. It shows 24:00 since the time value of a Date field is always `00:00:00`. I would remove the time part using `absoluteOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };`, this way it'll show only  July 16, 2023 at GMT +5:30

Comment: @RubenDG Thanks. I will do that. I would like to discuss the Relative part as well. I am working on that and I am trying to input the logic of days, weeks, months and years as well in the same method. As, sometimes the difference it much bigger than only few minutes or hours. If you could help in that. My logic is lacking the evaluation part correctly as for few scenarios I am getting seconds in (-) minus as well, because the date is of previous months or so.

Comment: @SFLearner the logic is the same: start from the biggest value (year), do not forget calling `Math.floor()`, then subtract it from the original value. Repeat for each realtive value. I updated the answer